# Power BI Edit interactions not working with my slicer

Tags: powerbi, filtering, powerbi-desktop, interaction

I am trying to set the interations on my Power Bi, that when I select a field on my graph or table, the options in the slicer will be filtered as well.
I have selected the filter option with Edit interactions, but my filter's fields are not filtering.
any advice??
[selected filter for slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJQyB.png)

I tried selecting the filter option for edit interaction, but isn't working

Comment: As far as I understand, highlighting visuals doesnt change the slicer values. However it can change if you make a selection in a slicer.